# What is the meaning of this.foo()?

Tags: javascript, this

I understand the concept of using `this` to assign values to a variable:

```
this.foo = 37;
```

But I am confused about using it in connection with a function invocation:

```
this.foo();
```

What is the meaning of this?

Comment: This question has been answered many times :)

Comment: In this case, nothing, since you can't call `37`. Otherwise it's calling a function on `this` (which is context-dependent) named `foo`. I'm not sure what the confusion actually is, though.

Comment: Well thank you @Olavi Sau - that is good to know ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just the context of how a function was called. In the global execution context (outside of a function) its the global object. In your case this is just some type of object that foo is a property on it. The property can be a value like an integer or even function.

```
var someObject = {
    foo1: 37,
    foo2: function () {
        return this.foo1;
    }
};

someObject.foo2.apply(someObject);
```

In the example above I created an object with two properties. One is an integer value and the other is a function. Then I call the function on the object using apply which allows us to set the context of the function. I set the context as the object I created so once inside the function I can reference it as this.

Comment: I'd be awfully hesitant in saying "usually it's the global object".

Comment: @DaveNewton fixed the wording. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you @AtheistP3ace. My question may not have been sufficiently clear as the voting and comments seem to indicate. So thank you for putting effort into answering it anyway - it did help me forward.

Comment: @David no problem. Glad it helped!

Answer (score 1):

Functions in JavaScript are first class objects. They can be treated like any other object.

They can be stored in variables. They can be stored in properties on other objects. They can be passed around as function arguments.

This is just an example of a property whose value is a function.

```js
var obj = {};
obj.foo = myFunction;
obj.foo();

function myFunction () {
    document.body.style.background = "red"; 
}
```